# Fetch API blob security violation

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy, fetch-api

Based on a fetch API that return a image/png I can [retrieve a blob object](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch#handling-blob-responses).

However problem comes when using

`URL.createObjectURL(pictureBlobObject);`

**Refused to load the image 'blob:http%3A//localhost...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src * data:".**

I have indeed a CSP rule defined at the `index.html`, however I'm not getting the reason for problem, and how not by passing the rule I can render the png.

Comment: Actually post your code?  Are you using `no-cors`?

Comment: @ellisbben I'm not using no-cors otherwise I would get a opaque response. I'm actually receiving a response and a valid blob that can be rendered if I remove the CSP policy.

Answer (score 0):

The CSP doesn't include the `blob:` source.
Neither `*` nor `data:` will match the blob image so all that should be needed is to add `blob:` to the end of the `img-src` directive.